# referring to files inside a jar or zip files in Linux

Tags: files, filesystems, zip

I am wondering if I can refer to files inside JAR or ZIP files using URLs. I mean, without using a tool (such as the Java Jar utility) but just at the operative system level.

For example, if I have a file `myfile` in a Jar file `myjar`, I would like to be able to write something like:

```
ls -name 'jar:file:/myjar!/myfile'
```

and see listed the file `myfile`

The context of this question is that I need to load Prolog files that are zipped in JARs files, but currently I have not discovered how to do this with the console based Prolog interpreter I am using (YAP).
In the hope that at the end the command for loading Prolog files will just submit the request to the operative system, I thought that I just need to find out the right way to refer to files inside JAR or ZIP files in such a way that the operative system understands what I am talking about (I am using OSX).

Comment: What this person did looks interesting .... is it standard? https://developer.gooddata.com/cloudconnect/manual/examples-of-file-url-in-writers.html

Answer (score 1):

The [AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net/) filesystem presents a view of the filesystem where every archive file `/path/to/foo.zip` is accessible as a directory `~/.avfs/path/to/foo/zip#`. AVFS provides read-only access to most common archive file formats.

Install AVFS (it's provided by many distributions; it requires [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/), which every modern unix supports). Run this command once and for all (you can run it from your `~/.profile`):

```
mountavfs
```

And thereafter:

```
ls /path/to/my.jar\#/myfile
```